# Swashbuckle Swagger Asp.Net Core Pass Api Key as Default Header Value in Request

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle

I have basic Api that accepts a default header value for `my-api-key` and the corresponding value.

I'm trying to get the Swagger UI to allow me to enter the header one time for Authorization and have the key/value passed along with every request.

So far, I've only been successful with explicitly adding the header as a parameter to every endpoint, but that isn't ideal.

Relevant code snippets:

```
        services.AddApiVersioning(
            options =>
            {
                // reporting api versions will return the headers "api-supported-versions" and "api-deprecated-versions"
                options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            });
        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
            options =>
            {
                // add the versioned api explorer, which also adds IApiVersionDescriptionProvider service
                // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

                // note: this option is only necessary when versioning by url segment. the SubstitutionFormat
                // can also be used to control the format of the API version in route templates
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Api", Version = "v1" });
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Api", Version = "v2" });

            // this isn't ideal as I have to fill in the Api Key on ever request
            //c.OperationFilter<ApiKeySwaggerFilter>();

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Name = "my-api-key",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                { new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                        {
                         // Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                            Name = ""
                            //In = ParameterLocation.Header
                            //Reference = new OpenApiReference()
                            //{
                            //  Id = "myToken",
                            //  Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                            //},
                }, new string[] { }
                }
            });
        });
```

---

```
app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Api v2");
    });
```

Corresponding image of where I'm at:

[image]

---

Corresponding minimal spike: https://github.com/aherrick/SwaggerSample

I feel this is close, but how do I get the Api Header to get passed on every request, without having to force the user to fill in parameter on every method request.

Comment: The users clicks the green "Authorize" button and enters the API key there. Then this API key will be sent with all requests. Is this not what you need?

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out with the following section update:

```
           c.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "Enter your Api Key below:",
                Name = "my-api-key",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
                {
                    {
                      new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "ApiKey"
                            },
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution.  I've just used this in a project of mine.